# Unity3D AssetBundle workflow

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game, I need to  click clothes icon to dynamically download and generate a clothes model, is my flow correct:

1. `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(myurl)` , since this is first download, I will download the assetbundle and store in the disk.
2. Then I use `LoadAsset()` to load the instantiate the clothes object.
3. Game closed.
4. Before enter the game, use  `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(myurl)` again, Unity will automatically detect I downloaded before, and I will directly load it into clothes gameobject. Make the clothes gameobject inactive and will be activated if I want it to be shown.

Comment: Looks good though, check the flow here.https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundles-Native.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flow seems ok, with one note:

4. If the app is closed and you use `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload` it will **not** load the clothes gameobject, or any other object for that matter.

You have to use the same flow even if the asset bundle is loaded from cache or not. This is good as you don't need special checks to make it work.

Note: Unity is deprecating `LoadFromCacheOrDownload` in favour of `UnityWebRequest`. You can read some more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle.html).

Comment: so even i have downloaded before, i still need to download again after opening again?

Comment: No, it will be cached. But you still need to create a game object from the asset bundle returned by `LoadFromCacheOrDownload`.

Comment: is it cached in memory or disk?

Comment: on disk, of course. Otherwise it will vanish as soon as the app is closed. When you load it via `LoadFromCacheOrDownload` it gets copied in memory.